# mysql script point to certain tmpdir

Tags: mysql, temporary-files

There's MySQL-5.6 with next TMPDIR variable definition:

```
tmpdir = /tmp:/var/lib/mysql/tmp
```

`/tmp` points to HDD volume, `/var/lib/mysql/tmp` is RAM disk.

There's "heavy" SQL script (let's call it "heavy.sql"), which creates many "heavy" temporary tables on disk during it's work. And they don't fit in RAM disk path.

Is there any way to set up "heavy.sql" to use only concrete TMPDIR path during it's execution (`/tmp`, not `/var/lib/mysql/tmp`)?

Comment: You can set the `tmpdir` to the location you want before executing the script and then reset it to it's initial state

Comment: Thank you. How can I do this, can you give an example?

Comment: Can you show what you are doing at this moment, calling sql scrip from the terminal ? or from bash file ? or I don't know : )

Comment: I'm simply "feeding" big .sql-file (about 4000 rows) directly to mysql from bash as cron job.

Comment: Can you post the content of this bash file in your question ?

Comment: You cannot change tmpdir dynamically (without a server restart). You can however set a tmpfs to a size larger than your physically ram, and it will simply swap to disk when needed. But generally, you could also test to simply assign the ram you currently reserve for the ramdisk to the mysql process and not use a ramdisk for tmp (which is used when mysql hasn't been assigned enough memory). It may have less of an impact as you think (as it may not even need to use temporary space in the first place or allows mysql to keep more cached data in memory).